# How to use Windows.Data.Pdf PdfDocument to get text from a PDF document to a TextBox?

Tags: c#, pdf, uwp

I have a UWP Desktop application for text editing and I need to get the text from a PDF file. I'm trying to use the Windows.Data.Pdf PdfDocument, but I couldn't. How can I do this? Any help is most welcome.

```
PdfDocument pdfDocument = await PdfDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(file);
```

Comment: I understand that, K J. And that's exactly why I created the question, I need an example of how to do this with Windows.Data.Pdf or another library.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to get the text from a PDF file

You could try to use the [OcrEngine Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.ocr.ocrengine?view=winrt-22000) to recognize the text from the PDF file. In the beginning, you need to convert the PDF file into some [SoftwareBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Graphics.Imaging.SoftwareBitmap?view=winrt-22000) objects by page, then you could call the **OcrEngine.RecognizeAsync method** to detect all the text on each pdf page.

Here is the sample I made and you could refer to it：

```
        FileOpenPicker fileOpenPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        fileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

        var inputFile = await fileOpenPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

        if (inputFile == null)
        {
            // The user cancelled the picking operation
            return;
        }
        //get the PDF file
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = await PdfDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(inputFile);
        //checke PDF page count
        uint pageCount = pdfDoc.PageCount;

        for (uint i = 0; i < pageCount; i++)
        {
            using (PdfPage page = pdfDoc.GetPage(i))
            {
                InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

                // Default is actual size. Render pdf page to stream
                await page.RenderToStreamAsync(stream);
                //convert the page into SoftwareBitmap
                BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
                SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);

                //detect the text
                var ocrEngine = OcrEngine.TryCreateFromLanguage(new Language("en"));
                OcrResult result = await ocrEngine.RecognizeAsync(softwareBitmap);
                var text = result.Text;

            }
        }
```

Comment: This approach allows for errors in the text due to optical recognition, but it is an option. Thanks.